start-stop-daemon does not start because: "process already running"
I have an init script to start qbittorrent-nox on my server. It works fine when I first start the server, but if I shut down the qbittorrent-nox process (service qbittorrent stop) it will not start again (service qbittorrent start), with this error:
process already running.

I am sure there is no process running, I looked with ps. this is the exact command to start:
start-stop-daemon --start --chdir '/home/testuser' --user 'testuser' --chuid 'testuser:testuser' --startas /usr/bin/env HOME="/home/testuser" /usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox

There are no files in /run related to qbittorrent.

Specifying --user with no other matching option causes start-stop-daemon to consider that the daemon is running if any process is found belonging to that user. As described in man 8 start-stop-daemon:

Note: Using this matching option alone will cause all
processes matching the user to be acted on.

In this case you should specify either --exec /usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox or an appropriate process name with --name.
